# Web API 405 Method Not Allowed In Remote

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Following is one my action:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutUnit(int id, Unit unit)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    if (id != unit.UnitId)
        return BadRequest();

    db.Entry(unit).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!UnitExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Following is the response I get:

```
Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 10:30:31 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Type: text/html
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Length: 1293
```

All actions of my controller works fine locally but once I deployed the same project on a remote server. I could not access only `PUT` and `DELETE` actions of my controller instead got the `405/Method Not Allowed` error. `web.config` and `webapiconfig.cs` are same and using the default structure. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Enabling The PUT Verb with Handlers and IIS 7.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joseph_fultz/archive/2009/07/23/enabling-the-put-verb-with-handlers-and-iis-7-0.aspx)