# Web Api HttpPost Method Not Allowed',

Tags: c#, api, rest

I am writing web api method which retrieves list of countries. Name of the method is **GetAllCountries**. Methods accepts many parameters (like pageno, pagesize, sortorder,other filters etc.). Instead of creating method with many arguments I have created Dto which has properties mentioned above. Since Get method in web api can accept only primitive datatypes or simple dto's, I have chosen GetAllCountries as post method (it is decorated with **HttpPost** attribute) so that it can accept complex dto.When I am invoking **GetAllCountries** method from client, I am getting error "StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers".
I know my method name is against web api convention(meaning method name starts with Get but it is actually a post). I have checked everything (like url etc) but still I could not figure why error is coming.
Following is the Code

```
        [HttpPost]
    public GetCountryListResponse GetAllCountries(GetAllCountriesRequest request)
    {
        return DestinationBl.GetAllCountries(request);
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide (a) code - at least the definition of the GetAllCountries method, and (b) the exact request, including headers, that you're making.

Comment: Could it be the IIS config? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382069/web-api-405-method-not-allowed-in-remote/25382446#25382446

Comment: Also 'Countries' is not spelled 'Conutries'. Not sure if that's a typo in here or your code.

Comment: I am running it from visual studio IDE. It is using IISExpress edition.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might have a problem with the method's input.
Try to add [FromBody] before the input parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public Countries GetAllConuntries([FromBody]YorObject obj)
{}
```

Comment: I am afraid this solution will work in case of complex dto where you have same property names at different levels inside dto(meaning properties located second or third level inside dto)

Comment: It might be serialization issue, the object you send is different from the object that the server is expecting to receive. try to call the function with no object at all (in the request and in the signature.
if it works, start checking the object properties by adding them one by one till you find the one that break the request